# Vue.js приложения с качественной архитектурой

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

мне прислали тестовое задания разработать todo приложения для приглашения на собеседования, условиям выполнения тестового задания помимо реализации функционала согласно тз было ещё и наличия качественно написанного кода, приложения я написал но мне сказали что качества кода не соответствует требованиям компании.

Можете дать ссылку на какой нибудь проект с грамотно организованной архитектурой и качественным кодом с комментариями со стеком технологий (vue.js, vuex, vue-router).

Проект мне необходим для обучения написания хорошо организованного кода

Comment: Это все субъективное мнение о качестве кода, не стоит на таком заморачиваться.

Comment: Чтобы измерить качество, необходимы критерии. Требования компании, как я понимаю, тоже озвучены не были. Просто отписку дали и всё. Держи всё это на гитхабчике. Полезный опыт.

Comment: В любом случаи мне не помешает изучения кода более опытных программистов

Comment: Для изучения советую посмотреть [vuejs/awesome-vue#projects-using-vuejs](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue) и [vuejs/awesome-vue#examples](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#examples). Местами код написан еще на ES5, но думаю это не проблема

Answer (score 2):

Кажется компания должна была озвучить требования к качеству кода.

Но вообще, как правило ожидают соблюдение [стайлгайда Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/index.html), использование паттернов, принципов SOLID и DRY, чтобы приложение в дальнейшем легко было поддерживать и легко было читать код. Возможно использование в полной мере синтаксиса ES6.

Стоит просто развиваться в сторону архитектуры и лучших практик, возможно прочитать книги **"Чистый код"** и **"Чистая архитектура"** Роберта Мартина. Ознакомиться с изданиями 
**O'Reilly**.

По существу из-за такого собеседования переживать не стоит, оно ничего не значит и не говорит о Вас как о специалисте, а решает всегда самообучение.

Также при таких собеседованиях стоит уточнять, почему реализация им показалась не качественной.
Бизнес - это деньги, не всегда эталонный код к этому ведёт. Если Вы сможете обосновать, что такая архитектура для такого приложения оптимальна с точки зрения бизнеса и в дальнейшем достаточно дёшево её можно улучшить (если это вообще понадобится), то это вероятно будет более лучшим решением и ответом, чем сам по себе идеальный код и проект.

Ссылку на стайлгайд я указал выше.

В комментариях уже указали ссылку на https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Обратите внимание также на канал Владилена Минина, он достаточно осведомлён о качестве кода, архитектуре и принципах, в частности [плейлист по CRM на Vue.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQ2i5cZ87ug&list=PLqKQF2ojwm3njNpksFCi8o-_c-9Vva_W0) может быть полезен.

По SOLID и Vue более менее понятно написано здесь: https://webdevblog.ru/kak-izbezhat-narusheniya-principov-solid-v-vue-js-prilozhenie/. На этом сайте вообще по сути описаны вещи, которые могут быть Вам полезны для улучшения навыков по проектированию систем.